I got a problem like ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE on my Ubuntu in all browsers
I can't load www.w3schools.com in all of my browsers in Ubuntu 22.04
I already switched to another router, but it didn't help me.
Also, I have already used this commands:
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo resolvectl flush-caches
and this:
chrome://net-internals/#dns  => Clear host cache
Maybe someone has already solved these problems?
